# Can I make webpack-dev-server run at the web root?

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack-dev-server for local Angular 2 development, which is of course, marvelous. The URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/webpack-dev-server/index.html
```

I would really like this to run at the root, so the URL might look like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/index.html
```

I'd like to do this to make my development routing code simpler. I could create a custom override, but I'd rather not have everyone fiddling about with overrides for the rest of the project lifespan.

Is there a configuration switch?

Comment: change the publicPath to publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',

Comment: @rashfmnb - That's interesting. I thought that was just for assets, not for the index.html file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **Inline mode** for that:

```
webpack-dev-server --inline
```

More info at [Webpack Dev Server/Automatic Refresh/Inline Mode](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#inline-mode).